# Check if date is between November 1 and March 1, if so then do something

Tags: javascript, validation, date

I want to check, in javascript, if the current date is between November first and March first, and if it is then perform something.

Here is my current code:

```
var today = new Date();
if (today.getMonth() >= 10 && today.getMonth() < 2) {
    $(document).ready( function(){ 
        $.fn.test(); 
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, using TodayDate = new Date();  But I am unable to format it properly.  I thought someone may have a much better idea on how to quickly perform it.  I was trying to use it in a mm/dd/yyyy format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
var today = new Date();
if (today.getMonth() >= 10 || today.getMonth() < 2) {
    // ... do stuff
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this give between March 1 and October 1?

Comment: No, the months start at 0 (so January is 0 and December is 11.) Try typing `(new Date).getMonth()` in console and it'll give you 11.

Comment: Either way I think you are getting the opposite of the question. This would give you the spring/summer/fall months and he wants the winter months

Comment: I have updated my code in OP, but it does not seem to work.  I am confident the code runs without the date validation.  Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, should be an || not &&

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date();
var MARCH_ZERO_INDEXED = 2, NOVEMBER_ZERO_INDEXED = 10;
if (MARCH_ZERO_INDEXED <= d.getMonth() && d.getMonth() < NOVEMBER_ZERO_INDEXED) {
  alert(d + " is between 1 Mar and 1 Nov");
} else {
  alert(d + " is between 1 Nov and 1 Mar of the next year");
}
```

or

```
var d = new Date();
var year = d.getFullYear();

var nov1 = new Date(year, 10 /* zero-indexed */, 1 /* one-indexed */);
var mar1 = new Date(year,  2, 1);

if (mar1 <= d && d < nov1) {
  alert(d + " is between 1 Mar and 1 Nov");
} else {
  alert(d + " is between 1 Nov and 1 Mar of the next year");
}
```

Both assume that you want to test using the JS interpreter's timezone.

Comment: Shouldn't `mar1` have `year + 1`?

Comment: There's a lot easier way to do this:

`(new Date).getDay()` and `(new Date).getMonth()` can be used to get number of day of month and number of month in year (starting with 0).
You can examine these to find out what you need.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat, I interpreted the OP as asking whether d is in [1-Mar, 1-Nov), but I think you're probably right that it is asking for the inverse.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp, Yeah.  That occurred to me right after I finished the first version.  Please see my edit.  I'm leaving the complicated version there since it is often easier to maintain code that compares like-quantities using their built-in `valueOf` scheme instead of using extra logic to decompose complex values.